# How to automatize intersect function in r?

Tags: r, matrix, vector, intersect, set-intersection

I have a task in which i have to find the "degree of intersection" in various dataframes containing the Top 50 Spotify Charts of multiples countries. In order to do this, im intersecting vectors of this data 1 by 1 using the code below, and transforming the sum of intersections of each country in a dataframe. Though this have worked, im asked to optimize the code, in order to get a network analysis out of it, so my question is: is there any function to reduce the code below? Thanks in advance, this is my first entry in this forum :)

The following code is an example. I've done the same code for every country in the list, and now i have to add 12 more so i really need to optimize the code.

```
I_arg_cl <- length(intersect(top50_cl$track.uri, top50_arg$track.uri))/50 
I_arg_pe <- length(intersect(top50_pe$track.uri, top50_arg$track.uri))/50 
I_arg_br <- length(intersect(top50_br$track.uri, top50_arg$track.uri))/50
I_arg_bo <- length(intersect(top50_bo$track.uri, top50_arg$track.uri))/50
I_arg_ec <- length(intersect(top50_ec$track.uri, top50_arg$track.uri))/50
I_arg_co <- length(intersect(top50_co$track.uri, top50_arg$track.uri))/50
I_arg_uy <- length(intersect(top50_uy$track.uri, top50_arg$track.uri))/50
I_arg_py <- length(intersect(top50_py$track.uri, top50_arg$track.uri))/50
I_arg_ve <- length(intersect(top50_ve$track.uri, top50_arg$track.uri))/50
```

Greetings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To automate such tasks whenever you have lot of dataframes put them in a list and apply the function with `lapply`. `ls(pattern = 'top50_')` would return the name of objects in global environment that has `'top50_'` in it. Using `setdiff` we remove `top50_arg` value from it.

```
data_vec <- setdiff(ls(pattern = 'top50_'), 'top50_arg')

result <- sapply(mget(data_vec), function(x) 
           length(intersect(x$track.uri, top50_arg$track.uri)))/50
```